# Read yml file with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, file-io

With OpenCV, I want to find keypoints in different images and save them on my hard disk. This works very well for the saving part. To save the keypoints I use:

```
Mat it;
it = imread( "pic1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect( (it), keypoints );
FileStorage fs("keypoint1.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write( fs , "keypoint", keypoints );
fs.release();
```

When I try to read the file again with:

```
vector<KeyPoint> keypoint1s;
FileStorage fs2("keypoint1.yml", FileStorage::READ);
FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["keypoint1"];
read( kptFileNode, keypoint1s );
fs2.release();
```

If I do it like that, "keypoint1s" is empty. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable name is wrong when reading:

```c
FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["keypoint1"];
```

should be

```c
FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["keypoint"];
```

This works for me:

```c
vector<int> keypoints;
keypoints.push_back(1);
keypoints.push_back(2);

FileStorage fs("keypoint1.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs , "keypoint", keypoints);
fs.release();

vector<int> newKeypoints;
FileStorage fs2("keypoint1.yml", FileStorage::READ);
FileNode kptFileNode = fs2["keypoint"];
read(kptFileNode, newKeypoints);
fs2.release();
```

Comment: Thanks! and sorry, completely oversaw this.